# Creating a Factory View in Backbone using javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I'm learning about JS prototype and Objects and following the Js patterns what would be the best way to create a Backbone view that returns a different Object depending on the passed model

```
    var MaleView = function() {
      this.initialize = function() {
        // stuff
      }
    },
    FemaleView = function() {
      this.initialize = function() {
        // stuff
      }
    },
    HumanFactory = function() {
      var self;

      if (this.model && this.model.get('type') === 'male') {
        self = new MaleView();
      }
      else {
        self = new FemaleView();
      }
      return self;
    },
    HumanView = Backbone.View.extend(new HumanFactory());
```

I know that this means that when the HumanView is initialized the model variable is not so the HumanView will always be a FemaleView. My question is what is the best way to achieve this using javascript inheritance.

What is the easiest way to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

It managed to slip my imagination the simple idea of moving the factory to the HumanView doing simple like.

```
var MaleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  this.initialize = function() {
    // stuff
  }
}),
FemaleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  this.initialize = function() {
    // stuff
  }
}),
HumanView = function(properties) {
  var self;
  if (properties) {
    if (properties.model.get('type') === 'male') {
      self = new MaleView(properties);
    }
    else {
      self = new FemaleView(properties);
    }
    return self;
  }
};
```